# Wiener-Ikehara Theorem and Signal Processing

Tags: nt.number-theory, fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, prime-number-theorem, signal-analysis

I am trying to understand the Wiener-Ikehara Tauberian theorem which can be a step to understanding the prime number theorem.  Let

$$ \hat{a}(s) = \int_0^\infty e^{-us}\, da(u) $$

with $a(u)$ some non-negative and increasing function on $\mathbb{R}$, and this Laplace transform converges for $s = \sigma + i \tau$ with $\sigma > 1$.
$$ \hat{a}(s) - \frac{1}{s-1} $$
should be continuous on $\sigma \geq 1$ half-plane.  Then
$$ \int_0^x 1 \, da(u)  = c e^x + o(e^x) $$

[Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TauberianTheorem.html) slams us with this rather abstract characterization:

> If $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$  then the translates of f span a dense subspace iff the Fourier transform is nonzero everywhere.

---

The statement (taken from [Montgomery-Vaughan](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521849039)) is actually really elaborate and I have many questions, but to fit the MO format, I'll ask just one.  In my mind, I am linking these results to the Tauberian Theorems one finds in a good Complex Analysis textbook.

The proof of this theorem seems to rest on two lemmas.  First, a Laplace transform identity:
$$ \mathcal{L}:   e^u \to \frac{1}{s-1} $$
I think that just says: $\int_0^\infty e^{-u(1-s)} \, du = \frac{1}{s-1}$ but the main point is when we have $$\sum \Lambda(n) n^{-s} = \frac{1}{s-1}  + O(...)$$ that pole gets turned into an exponential main term, and we are left bounding the noise term - potentially larger than the main term itself!

---

We estimate something smaller than $\int 1 \, da(u)$:

$$ \int_0^x e^{-\delta u} \, da(u) < e^x \big[ o(1) + (1 + \epsilon) \big]$$

In order to do as much Montgomery and Vaughan use a single "trigonometric" lemma.  There exist two functions $f\pm (x) \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$

$$ f_-(x) \leq e^{-x} \mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{R}^-} \leq f_+(x) $$

where $f_\pm (x)$ are made of only specific wavelengths, $ \hat{f}(t)= 0$ unless $|t| < T$.  Finally the total mass of $f$ is somewhat near $1$:
$$ 1 - \epsilon < \int_\mathbb{R} f_-(x) dx  
< \int_\mathbb{R} f_+(x) dx < 1 + \epsilon $$
How is such a construction achieved: This looks somewhat like a [low pass filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter):

[image]

The book uses a mix of the [Fejer Kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r_kernel) and Jackson Kernel.  Can anyone comment on why this proof looks more and more like [signal processing](http://www-math.mit.edu/~gs/papers/newsigproc.pdf) ?

Comment: my apologies in advance I'm trying here